# How to generate multiple output directories from two or more main.scss files with webpack

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, webpack, web-frontend

In this project the css and js are the same. The difference is in the css, it is the colors used for each project. I await suggestions on how to do this. Thanks

output the structure with the desired web package.

```
dist /
    - publicA
        - css
        - js
    - publicB
        - css
        - js
```

Work area with vue or react

```
src /
    components
    ...
    ...
    main.js
```

my content main.js

```
    import "../resources/sources/*.scss"

    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    ..
```

Directory where global styles can be found

```
resources/scss /
    - publicA /
        - scss /
            _custom.scss
            _common.scss
            // included custom y common
            main.scss
    - publicA /
        - scss 
            _custom.scss
            _common.scss
            // included custom y common
            main.scss
```

Content my config webpack

```
const config = {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + `dist/js/[name].min.js` ),
        //publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: `js/[name].min.js`
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                use: "asset",
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
            },
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss|sass)$/,
                use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        {
                            loader: 'css-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            loader: 'sass-loader',
                            options: {
                                sourceMap: true,
                            }
                        }                   
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
        },
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `css/[name].min.css`
        })
    ]
};

``
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see the file-loader, https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader
it has a optional function named name()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQoaX.png)

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.